# Using Google Tag Manager to define the page type

Tags: javascript, tag-manager

So, I am looking to add a tag that I want to use for A/B testing, however we don't have a page-type URL structure. Fortunately the tool can recognise page type if I pass it by Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.isProductPage = true;
</script>
```

I have been told to use the above, I have created the script in Google Tag Manager (GTM), however I now need to know how to make this run on those pages in GTM.

I have looked through the code and there are div class that are unique to each page, can I use this as an indication of page type?

Answer (score 1):

So I found a workaround using the GTM Data Layer.

The Data Layer passes values from the page to GTM, within that I had a Brand variable - this wouldn't populate on any page other than Product detail pages.

I could then create the rule where Brand wasn't null using RegEx.

This script now runs on Product Pages only.

Boom!